# How to trigger multiple UIGestureRecognizers without lifting finger from screen

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have adjacent views on the screen, and each have a different `UIGestureRecognizer`. What I want is if I touch down in one view and move into an adjacent view, the adjacent view's gesture recognizer will start detecting the touches.

What is currently happening is if I touch down in one view and move out of that view's frame, the initial view's gesture recognizer will continue to receive calls to `touchChanged` until my finger has lifted. And it doesn't matter if I change the `state` of the gesture recognizer to `.ended`, `.failed`, or `.cancelled`, no other gesture recognizers will receive calls to their `touch` methods until my finger is lifted.

How can I ensure a gesture recognizer will be triggered when the touch is in its view's bounds, and end when it leaves them, without having to handle touch events from the superview?

Here is the custom `UIGestureRecognizer` I implemented to do this:

```
class GestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    override init(target: Any?, action: Selector?) {
        super.init(target: target, action: action)
        delegate = self
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
        state = .began
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        super.touchesMoved(touches, with: event)
        if state == .began {state = .ended}
        else {state = .began}
    }

    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return otherGestureRecognizer is GestureRecognizer
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, Just write this delegate method in your controller, and return true.

read this once.
https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uigesturerecognizerdelegate/1624208-gesturerecognizer

Comment: i believe my delegate method encapsulates your recommendation, and it doesn't work

Comment: if you gesture object is not type of GestureRecognizer, then it will not work.

Comment: remove touches method and try, it will create problem with gesture.

Comment: i removed all `touch` methods and now action is never triggered

Comment: that is all the relevant code. what more do you need other than the `UIGestureRecognizer` subclass?

Comment: it's just the standard:         `mView.addGestureRecognizer(GestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(onViewTouched)))`. in the `action` there is a print statement which is how i know when it  is called and which view is being interacted with

Comment: ok, you should write that delegate method in view controller instead of gesture class, because can't able to recognise delegate.

Comment: i don't understand what you're trying to say. `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` is a protocol, what does it matter whether the protocol is the view controller or the gesture recognizer?

Comment: i don't know what you mean. there is only one gesture recognizer and i posted the code to it in the question. if you want the code in the `action`, there is nothing but a print statement